# Angular material tab with "search input" as last tab

Tags: angular-material

How do we create a "search input" or "add button" as the last tab of an **Angular Material tabs component**?

I did not see indication from [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) that this can be done. Can someone confirm if this is possible? Workarounds would be appreciated too.

The screenshot shows an example of what I would like: the "search input" as the last tab item:

[image]

The screenshot was taken from a random (i.e. any) YouTube channel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I do not think that having a input box inside the mat-tab is possible without editing the component, you can have an input box for the search after the mat-tab-group, and bring it into the same row as the mat-tab-group, e.g. by using `flex` in your CSS.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<mat-tab-group class="tabs">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<mat-form-field class="input">
  <input matInput placeholder="Search" >
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.input {
margin-top: 0.5%;
}
```

will produce this:

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBZ8e.png)

[Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5y8nps)

May need some tinkering for display on mobile devices.

Comment: The thing I didn't like about this implementation was that this puts two elements side by side when you want the input inside the mat-tab-header. This actually shrinks the tab group width to accommodate for the width of the input. For better or worse, I made the containers position relative and the inputs position absolute and placed it to the right. Just be sure to set the z-index to a large number for the input so it gets the mouse events.

Comment: @agentnate: With the current Angular Material, it's even easier! You can simply put the form-field in the mat-tab-label template, disable the mat-tab and then you can use the input-field inside the tab-header without it navigating to the tab. I'll try to update my answer later today with a working example.